# MySQL query to return closest place comparing to csv stored coordinates along with the distance in meters

Tags: mysql

**I have these two tables:**

1. Table locations

   | coords |
   | --- |
   | 28.08982880911016,-31.649963296195086 |
2. Table places

   | lat | lon | place |
   | --- | --- | --- |
   | 28.08982880911016 | -31.649963296195086 | Test |

I want a MySQL (version 5.7.41 compatible) query which can return all records in table 1; however, I do not want to display the coords value as they stored; instead, I want to use ST_Distance_Sphere or Haversine formula to check each coords with the nearest place respecting these cases:

1. If the nearest value is less than 300 meter it returns that corresponding place value
2. If the nearest value is between 300 and 1500 meters it returns: "Near " + the value of the corresponding place + "~" + the nearest value in meters + "m"
3. If the nearest value is more than 1500 it returns "N/A" 3.

Please note that I have around a million records in the table locations, so I need the simplest query with minimal performance impact.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere

Comment: What are your min and max values for lat and lon in locations table? How many rows in places table? Can you add geo columns to these tables (or change existing) to improve performance? Do you really need to support 5.7 when it goes EOL later this year?

Comment: You are wasting a lot of space by storing your location to such high precision. It will also carry greater overhead when doing your distance calculations. For most mapping applications 5 or 6 dp will be more than enough. Have a quick look at [this article](https://rapidlasso.com/2019/05/06/how-many-decimal-digits-for-storing-longitude-latitude/).

Answer (score 0):

Performing the distance calculation between all `locations` and all `places` would be very expensive so we will create a bounding box, which can use available indices to get a subset of `places` on which to perform the distance calculations.

We are building a bounding box slightly bigger than the 1500m radius we are interested in (to allow for inaccuracy):

```
dist in degrees latitude = (dist / rEarth) * (180 / pi)
dist in degrees longitude = (dist / rEarth) * (180 / pi) / cos(latitude * pi/180)

dist = 1.550 km
rEarth ≈ 6371 km

dist in degrees latitude = (dist / rEarth) * (180 / pi)
dist in degrees latitude = (1.55 / 6371) * (180 / pi)
dist in degrees latitude = DEGREES(1.55/6371)
dist in degrees latitude = 0.013939

dist in degrees longitude = (dist / rEarth) * (180 / pi) / cos(latitude * pi/180)
dist in degrees longitude = 0.013939 / COS(RADIANS(latitude))
```

Start the join with a 3.100 km x 3.100 km bounding box centered on the location.coords
Then do point to point distance calc for the entities found:

```sql
SELECT *,
    /*
     * We are pre-splitting the coords here so we don't have to do
     * it repeatedly inside the correlated sub-query
     */
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(l.coords, ',', 1) AS loc_lat,
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(l.coords, ',', -1) AS loc_lon,
    (
        SELECT CONCAT(
                ROUND(ST_Distance_Sphere(
                    ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', REPLACE(l.coords, ',', ' '),')')),
                    ST_GeomFromText(CONCAT('POINT(', lat, ' ', lon,')'))
                ), -1),
                '::',
                place
            ) dist
        FROM places
        WHERE lat BETWEEN loc_lat - 0.013939 AND loc_lat + 0.013939
        AND lon BETWEEN loc_lon - (0.013939 / COS(RADIANS(loc_lat))) AND loc_lon + (0.013939 / COS(RADIANS(loc_lat)))
        HAVING dist <= 1500
        ORDER BY dist ASC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS place,
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(place, '::', 1) < 300 THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(place, '::', -1)
                WHEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(place, '::', 1) BETWEEN 300 AND 1500 THEN CONCAT('Near ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(place, '::', -1), '~', SUBSTRING_INDEX(place, '::', 1))
                ELSE 'N/A'
            END
    ) AS place_text
FROM locations l;
```

This query will work but how it will perform is another matter entirely. Ideally, you should have two composite indices on places: `(lat, lon)` and `(lon, lat)` but having at least one of these is critical, otherwise you will be constantly table scanning.